# Why vectors [2, 3] and [-2, -3] are the same?

Tags: linear-algebra

I watched [TedEd talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml4NSzCQobk) where it says vectors [2, 3] and [-2, -3] are the same, because array gets meaning as a vector when assigned coordinate basis...
Which did not make sense to me.
Could someone explain?
Thanks

Comment: "I watched TedEd talk" - do link to it please.

Comment: If you give us the link to the talk, then maybe we can help.

Comment: @J.M. lined, done

Comment: @5xum it is done

Comment: The short answer is that he doesn't claim the *vectors* $[2,3]$ and $[-2,-3]$ are the same. He says that the vectors, **represented** by the **arrays** $[2,3]$ and $[-2,-3]$ are the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you describe a vector in a space, you can use a coordinate system to label that vector. If Sally uses a coordinate system in 2d space are $\hat{i} = \langle 1, 0 \rangle$ and $\hat{j} = \langle 0, 1\rangle$ then a vector exists in that space labeled as 2 $\hat{i}$ vectors and 3 $\hat{j}$ vectors summed together $2\hat{i} + 3\hat{j}$.

But if another person, Bob, uses the coordinate system $\hat{i'} = \langle -1, 0 \rangle$ and $\hat{j'} = \langle 0, -1\rangle$ then the vector that Sally sees as $\langle 2,3\rangle$ would be described by Bob as $-2$ $\hat{i'}$ vectors and $-3$ $\hat{j'}$ vectors summed together $-2\hat{i'} - 3\hat{j'} = \langle -2, -3\rangle$.

They see the same object but they just describe it differently.